# How can I tell if an application is using XWayland?

Tags: xorg, wayland

I'm troubleshooting some issues to do with multiple monitors and HiDPI on Wayland. I've learnt from online resources that applications on XWayland may not handle this use-case as expected. So now I want to know which applications are using XWayland, and which aren't.

How can I tell if an application is using XWayland or not?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## TL;DR: [`xlsclients`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xlsclients)

Running `xlsclients` in a terminal will list all the apps currently running which are using XWayland.

---

## For fun: Use [`xeyes`](https://medium.com/@bugaevc/how-to-easily-determine-if-an-app-runs-on-xwayland-or-on-wayland-natively-8191b506ab9a)!

[image]

```
xeyes - a follow the mouse X demo
```

When you launch `xeyes`, it connects to the XWayland server and asks for the mouse position. If the mouse is currently over a window of an app that uses XWayland, XWayland knows the mouse position and can report it back to `xeyes` via the X11 protocol. But if the mouse is over a native Wayland client, XWayland can't get that — so the eyes will remain still even if you move your mouse.

---

## Alt: [`xwininfo`](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/kx5yq6/comment/gj8mlrg/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Run `xwininfo` in a terminal window — when you hover over an xwayland window the mouse pointer will turn into a `+` sign. If you click the window it'll display some information and end, but it won't do anything with native Wayland windows.You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to end it.

Comment: Okay, I officially love that `xeyes` hack!

Comment: When running OBS Studio 29.0.2, xeyes and xwininfo indicate it uses XWayland but xlsclients doesn't list it.